# How to implement two way payment gateway in flutter (accept and refund)?

Tags: flutter, payment

I want to initiate transactions to accept money from users via UPI and other payments modes, When needed platform should be able to refund or credit back through the saved methods.

Answer (score 1):

see upi_india package, [https://pub.dev/packages/upi_india](http://dart%20package)

Docs from web

Apps supported by this plugin are:

```
PayTM
Google Pay
BHIM
PhonePe
Mi Pay
Amozon Pay
Truecaller
My Airtel
```

"refund or credit back through the saved methods" -write your own logic for that because u basically have the upi id of the payment

Comment: Can i send more amount than payed?

Comment: yes, see that part is dependent how you write your logic, your bank . I dont think it will be simple as loading a library though.